# Factory data reset is not complete

Tags: 2.2-froyo, factory-reset

I'd like to reset my tablet to factory settings. I used this option in my device but this was not complete. In the directory structure there are old application settings and I want to erase it to have fresh new installed operating system.
I haven't found another reset or reinstall possibilities.

My device is `Archos 7`

Comment: Where?  If they're not in `/data/data/` then it's stuff you should delete manually if you want to, like on internal SD.  This is where pictures and so on go so it isn't wiped.

Comment: I don't want to only delete.

Comment: What do you mean?  A factory reset clears (deletes) data and cache, and restores the OS to its original state.  If there are leftover files that are not part of that process and you delete the ones that didn't come with your device, then it will end up exactly how it was when you bought it.

Comment: I'd like to have fresh new system. Now there are old files and old settings. When you reinstall Linux or Windows it's completely new.

Comment: Not true.  You can reinstall either without formatting.  They also won't wipe a secondary drive (like the SD storage) unless you explicitly tell them too.  If you would answer the question of where these files are, we could confirm for sure what's happening here.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the files in question are on the sdcard, try deleting any suspicious-looking files on there (don't forget about hidden files beginning with a . )

Comment: Deleting is not what I want. I'd like to completely reinstall the system.

Comment: This is the correct answer, @xralf. A factory reset will *not* erase your SD card, where many apps store data and configuration info.  This is by design, to protect any files you may have loaded onto your SD card.  So if you want to completely "reinstall", you also need to either reformat the SD card or erase all data on it manually.  

Think of the SD card as being a flash drive connected to a Linux box, and that this is where /home is mounted.  If you reinstall Linux on the box and then remount /home, all your settings will still be there from your previous install.

Comment: I have a possibility of SD card, but I don't have it now. If you have a virus in Windows system, you can reinstall it and this is what I want to do. I want to have clean system and be sure that it's completely clean.

Comment: please clarify: you don't think you have have an sdcard right? If so, it's possible you have one anyway, it's become fashionable among manufacturers lately to include a non-removable sdcard (like in the last two nexus devices) and this might be the case with your tablet. My advice is the same: Mount it in usb mass storage mode on your computer and delete any suspicious-looking directories.

Comment: @AndreyLosev I look's that there is internal SD card. The storage is divided into two categories (Internal flash storage and Internal device storage). Maybe one is for system and the other for data. So you advise to format the part for the data and I will have clean system?

Comment: Yes, delete everything in the system part (but not the partition itself) and any hidden files in your internal flash storage. Then, use the system wipe feature again (just in case) and you should be good to go :)